# How to create OpsWorks users using CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-opsworks

I am trying to create a `CloudFormation` template that deploys my `OpsWorks` stack and layers and some other `AWS` resources. I would like to manage the users of my `OpsWorks` instances using the `Permissions` feature they offer.

I have been able to manage those users using the UI and the CLI, however I cannot find anywhere how to that with `CloudFormation`. I have been reading through the documentation and it seems there is no resource specified for it. Does `CloudFormation` not have access to all resources in the `AWS` APIs?

Comment: it's possible that CloudFormation does not have access to some UI elements or even APIs. Are you talking about Linux users or AWS IAM Users?

Comment: You can import AWS IAM Users into OpsWorks and OpsWorks will create those users into your Linux machines. In the UI you can define who can be a sudoer and who can SSH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudFormation doesn't support OpsWorks user. But it's still possible, you can use CloudFormation custom resource to create opsworks user:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. Do you know if it's required to do it though SNS or Lambda? I cannot seem to find any other examples for other ServiceTokens.